# UIView not updating after delete UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have more than 4 images in the screen. Every image has id, then sharing the image id to email. After deleting any of the image from view, still i'm getting all the image ids including deleting image id. How to get update image ids without deleted image id.

```
     mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,200,350,199)];
          ageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


                [mmageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1]] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {


                }];

                NSLog(@"Tag %d",[sender tag]);

                [mmageView setTag:[sender tag]-1];


                ObjectAddedToScreen *object = [[ObjectAddedToScreen alloc] init];
                object.productDescription = [descript_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1];
                object.view = mmageView;
                [self.objectsAddedToScreen addObject:object];

object.object_sku=[sku_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1];

              [self.view addSubview:mmageView];
```

Delete the image using Longpress:

```
-(void)dblongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender{

 CGPoint tapLocation1 = [sender locationInView: self.view];
            for (UIImageView *imageeView1 in self.view.subviews) {
                if (CGRectContainsPoint(imageeView1.frame, tapLocation1)) {

                    // [imageeView1 removeFromSuperview];

                    [imageeView1 setHidden:YES];


}
                }
            }
```

Comment: `Image id = tag` the one you are setting ? How are you getting ids ?

Comment: check edited code. Each image has object_sku number from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW hidden is not equal to remove :P

Try like this.

```
NSArray *subViewsArray = self.view.subviews;
    CGPoint tapLocation1 = [sender locationInView: self.view];

    for(UIView *v in subViewsArray){
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        {
            UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)v;{
                if (CGRectContainsPoint(imageView.frame, tapLocation1)){

                    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried [imageeView1 removeFromSuperview]; also...but it didn't work

Comment: then check your if condition. if (CGRectContainsPoint**** this get called ?

Comment: when i use [imageeView1 removeFromSuperview]; the image is deleting from superview. But when i share or save the update view the deleted image also appear. This is the problem

Comment: O my God - this is the issue. When removing from superview remove it from descript_array too.

Comment: can you come to chat 231jar@gmail.com. please help this

Comment: then remove it from container class, which ever container class you are using to store imageViews or their URLs. Because next time whenever you save or share it will be appear again.

Comment: Can you help this. I have tag for [mmageView setTag:[sender tag]-1];. How can delete particular tag of image..then i can get solution

Comment: `[[self.view viewWithTag:tag] removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: you need some identity that image with tag=selectedTag then remove it. The image on which you do long press get its tag and then [[self.view viewWithTag:tag] removeFromSuperview]; problem solved.

Comment: I have tag for imageview [mmageView setTag:[sender tag]-1];. How to use this for delete

Comment: I think your question is you have tag at imageView creation time. Now when deleting how to get that specific imageView tag and delete it ? right ? really confusing what exactly is your issue.

Comment: yes..I have imageView tag (id) and delete particular tag then i can get updated imageview from view..

Comment: dblongpress method is doing same functionality. Just check frame of imageView is being matched with long-pressed image. If YES it should work. If NO, just check this thing. You are doing right buddy.

Comment: I didn't understand. What should i do?

Comment: @ShahabQureshi: Please help this

Comment: I told you each and every possible solution. What else you want from me.